# I have followed exactly what the instructor in a pre recorded webinar has entered a name error occured

Tags: python, import, flopy

here is a screenshot of the name error i am talking about.

[image: 1]

I have entered what the instructor in a pre-recorded webinar has entered in his screen. i can't ask follow-up questions to the instructor since webinar has already passed.

Comment: Show code and error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: # Assign model name and create modflow model object
modelname='tutorial1'
modelpath='E:/Model'
mf = flopy.modflow.Modflow(modelname, model_ws=modelpath,exe_name='E:/modflow flopy/GroundwaterModelWithFlopy/Exe/mf2005')

Comment: error message:   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a4a901ae4af0> in <module>
      2 modelname='tutorial1'
      3 modelpath='E:/Model'
----> 4 mf = flopy.modflow.Modflow(modelname, model_ws=modelpath,exe_name='E:/modflow flopy/GroundwaterModelWithFlopy/Exe/mf2005')

NameError: name 'flopy' is not defined

Comment: In the question, not as comment.

Comment: You need to install flopy, either with `pip` or `anaconda`

Comment: When running in a notebook, be sure to 'run all'.  In your screen shot, if you tried running the 2nd notebook cell without initially running the first cell, that is one potential source of your problem...flopy hasn't been loaded yet.